# How to enable disable motion detection DCS-933L(D-link Cam) with Curl?

Tags: php, curl, camera

I try this code in php but I don't solve!

```
$s = $motion = 1;
$camIp = "192.168.1.124";
$camUser = "admin";
$camPass = "gatelliHome";

$params = "ReplySuccessPage=motion.htm&ReplyErrorPage=motion.htm&MotionDetectionEnable=$motion&MotionDetectionSensitivity=85&ConfigSystemMotion=Save";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$camIp/motion.cgi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$camUser:$camPass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I isn't certain the $url and $params are correct!

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing `curl_exec($ch);` to see if there is any output?

Comment: nothing! I try to change url with another one, for example http://$camIp/motion.htm or http://$camIp/setSystemMotion, but I have empty output!

Comment: Is there any documentation from the manufacturer about doing this?